# Library for doing A/B tests in a web app

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I made a simple library to help me doing A/B tests in a web app. The idea is simple: I have two or more page options (URL) for a given page and every call to the library method should give me a URL so at the end all options were given the same traffic.

My questions are:

- Is this 100% thread safe?
- Is this performatic (I'm worried about the locks in a multithreaded (web) environment)?
- Did I use the best data structure for it?
- Can it be more readable?

Here are the tests and the implementation:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ABTestTest    
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        ABTest.ResetAll();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetUrlWithTwoCandidates()
    {
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url1.aspx");
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url2.aspx");

        ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento").Should().Be.EqualTo("Url1.aspx");
        ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento").Should().Be.EqualTo("Url2.aspx");
        ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento").Should().Be.EqualTo("Url1.aspx");
        ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento").Should().Be.EqualTo("Url2.aspx");
        ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento").Should().Be.EqualTo("Url1.aspx");
        ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento").Should().Be.EqualTo("Url2.aspx");
        ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento").Should().Be.EqualTo("Url1.aspx");
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetUrlWithThreeCandidates()
    {
        var OptionsSelected = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        OptionsSelected.Add("Url1.aspx", 0);
        OptionsSelected.Add("Url2.aspx", 0);
        OptionsSelected.Add("Url3.aspx", 0);

        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url1.aspx");
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url2.aspx");
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url3.aspx");

        var nextUrl = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            nextUrl = ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento");

            OptionsSelected[nextUrl]++;
        }

        OptionsSelected["Url1.aspx"].Should().Be.EqualTo(3);
        OptionsSelected["Url2.aspx"].Should().Be.EqualTo(3);
        OptionsSelected["Url3.aspx"].Should().Be.EqualTo(3);
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetUrlWithThreeCandidatesThreaded()
    {
        var OptionsSelected = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        OptionsSelected.Add("Url1.aspx", 0);
        OptionsSelected.Add("Url2.aspx", 0);
        OptionsSelected.Add("Url3.aspx", 0);

        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url1.aspx");
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url2.aspx");
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url3.aspx");

        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(3, 3);

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((object state) =>
            {
                var nextUrl = ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento");

                OptionsSelected[nextUrl]++;
            });                
        }

        while (OptionsSelected.Select(x => x.Value).Sum() != 9)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        OptionsSelected["Url1.aspx"].Should().Be.EqualTo(3);
        OptionsSelected["Url2.aspx"].Should().Be.EqualTo(3);
        OptionsSelected["Url3.aspx"].Should().Be.EqualTo(3);
    }
}

public class ABTest
{
    private volatile static Hashtable NextOption = new Hashtable();
    private static Hashtable Options = new Hashtable();

    public static void ResetAll()
    {
        lock (NextOption)
        {
            NextOption = new Hashtable();
        }
        lock (Options)
        {
            Options = new Hashtable();
        }
    }

    public static void RegisterUrl(string key, string url)
    {
        if (Options.ContainsKey(key.GetHashCode()))
        {
            lock (Options)
            {
                ((List<ABTestOption>)Options[key.GetHashCode()]).Add(new ABTestOption()
                {
                    Url = url,
                    Count = 0
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if (!Options.ContainsKey(key.GetHashCode()))
            {
                lock (Options)
                {
                    if (!Options.ContainsKey(key.GetHashCode()))
                    {
                        Options.Add(
                            key.GetHashCode(),
                            new List<ABTestOption>() { 
                            new ABTestOption() { 
                                Url = url, 
                                Count = 0 
                            } 
                        });
                    }
                }
            }


            if (!NextOption.ContainsKey(key.GetHashCode()))
            {
                lock (NextOption)
                {
                    if (!NextOption.ContainsKey(key.GetHashCode()))
                    {
                        NextOption.Add(key.GetHashCode(), url);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static string GetUrl(string key)
    {
        lock (NextOption)
        {
            var nextUrl = (string)NextOption[key.GetHashCode()];

            var keyOptions = (List<ABTestOption>)Options[key.GetHashCode()];
            var selectedOption = keyOptions.Where(x => x.Url == nextUrl).First();
            selectedOption.Count++;

            NextOption.Remove(key.GetHashCode());
            NextOption.Add(key.GetHashCode(), keyOptions.OrderBy(x => x.Count).First().Url);

            return nextUrl;
        }
    }

    private class ABTestOption
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is not thread safe:

```
    lock (NextOption)
    {
        NextOption = new Hashtable();
    }
```

The problem is that the object being used to synchronize is re-assigned.  That means a subsequent caller will acquire a different lock.

It's conceivable that two writer threads hit `RegisterUrl` and each see a different lock, but end up adding concurrently to the same hash table, which is a harmful race condition.  There are also more subtle problems if two threads are both calling `ResetAll` and a third thread is inserting.

You should do something like this:

```
object NextOptionLock = new object();
Hashtable NextOption = new Hashtable();

lock (NextOptionLock)
{
    NextOption = new HashTable();
}
```

I would do this for all other places where you use `lock(/* ... */)`.  It's a good practice to keep the lock object separate from the data being protected.

---

This next part looked kind of suspicious to me because its thread safety depends on the implementation of `Hashtable`:

```
    if (Options.ContainsKey(key.GetHashCode()))
    {
        lock (Options)
        {
            ((List)Options[key.GetHashCode()]).Add(new ABTestOption()
```

The question is whether or not it's safe to call `ContainsKey` while another thread does `Add`.  According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) it is safe:

> Hashtable is thread safe for use by multiple reader threads and a single writing thread. It is thread safe for multi-thread use when only one of the threads perform write (update) operations, which allows for lock-free reads provided that the writers are serialized to the Hashtable.

So while it might be a red flag for someone auditing for concurrency problems, it seems OK.

---

Your use of `GetHashCode` looks a little weird.  Don't MS's classes do this for you when you use an object as a hash table key?

Also, why use a non-generic class like `Hashtable`?  I see from MSDN that `Dictionary<K,V>` does not allow reads to be overlapped with a write in the same way that `Hashtable`'s documentation claims, so maybe that's the reason...  Have you looked at `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: I can see that you suggested the double check lock pattern (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for the first part of your review. I guess you are right. I'm going to change that. As for the use o GetHashCode I already removed it based on a friend´s review. Will look into the ConcurrentDictionary. Thanks!

Comment: @tucaz - Actually this is not the double-check lock pattern.  (And the double-check lock pattern is broken on some CPU architectures - though probably not those that .NET supports.)  I am suggesting you keep the locks and data separate, so that if you re-initialize the data, your code is still using the same lock...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way which is hopefully easy to read.

I'm sure someone smarter than me can (and will) point out any potential issues with this suggestion.

The `options` field is never null and the set operation of the field is atomic so I don't think you need a lock around that.

```
public static class ABTest
{
    private static IDictionary<string, ABTestOption> options = new Dictionary<string, ABTestOption>();
    private readonly static object locker = new object();

    public static string GetUrl(string key)
    {
        ABTestOption option;

        lock (locker)
        {
            if (!options.TryGetValue(key, out option))
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return option.GetNextUrl();
    }

    public static void RegisterUrl(string key, string url)
    {
        ABTestOption option;

        lock (locker)
        {
            if (!options.TryGetValue(key, out option))
            {
                option = new ABTestOption();
                options[key] = option;
            }
        }

        option.AddUrl(url);
    }

    public static void ResetAll()
    {
        options = new Dictionary<string, ABTestOption>();
    }

    private class ABTestOption
    {
        private readonly object locker = new object();
        private readonly List<string> urls = new List<string>();
        private int totalCallCount = -1;

        public void AddUrl(string url)
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                if (!this.urls.Contains(url))
                {
                    this.urls.Add(url);
                }
            }
        }

        internal string GetNextUrl()
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                int urlCount = this.urls.Count;
                int position = Interlocked.Increment(ref this.totalCallCount) % urlCount;

                return this.urls[position];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't get your threadpool test to build as your `for` statements are incomplete and I wasn't sure how they should be completed so I used these two tests instead:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ABTestTest
{
    [Test]
    public void GetUrlWithTwoCandidates()
    {
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url1.aspx");
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url2.aspx");

        Assert.AreEqual("Url1.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Url2.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Url1.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Url2.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetUrlWithThreeCandidates()
    {
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url1.aspx");
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url2.aspx");
        ABTest.RegisterUrl("CarrinhoPagamento", "Url3.aspx");

        Assert.AreEqual("Url1.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Url2.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Url3.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Url1.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Url2.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Url3.aspx", ABTest.GetUrl("CarrinhoPagamento"));
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        ABTest.ResetAll();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated following feedback.

The lock is simple and quite fast, you could get more throughput by using a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) but that is more complicated and unless you can prove that the lock causes significant blocking I would leave it at that initially.

Comment: I fixed the third test now. Sorry for that.

Comment: The concurrency section of the MSDN doc for `Dictionary<K,V>` says that reads can be concurrent but cannot be overlapped with a write: "A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: @asveikau - good point, the original idea would work for multiple readers (with no writers) or a multiple writers (with no readers) but not a mixture. I'll update it to add locks around the reads too.